# PHP cURL, extract an XML response

Tags: php, curl

I am invoking PHP cURL method on a server and the response is XML type. cURL is saving the output (after removing the tags) in a scalar type variable. Is there a way to store it in an object/hash/array so that it's easy to parse?

Comment: Could you expand on what you mean by "after removing the tags".

Answer (score 117, accepted):

```
<?php
function download_page($path){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$path);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);
    $retValue = curl_exec($ch);          
    curl_close($ch);
    return $retValue;
}

$sXML = download_page('http://alanstorm.com/atom');
$oXML = new SimpleXMLElement($sXML);

foreach($oXML->entry as $oEntry){
    echo $oEntry->title . "\n";
}
```

Comment: How do we read ![CDATA using this? when I print $oXML I don't see ![CDATA but on htmlentities I am able to see it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970602/php-how-to-handle-cdata-with-simplexmlelement

Answer (score 8):

Just add `header('Content-type: application/xml');` before your echo of the XML response and you will see an XML page.

Answer (score 5):

Example:

```
<songs>
<song dateplayed="2011-07-24 19:40:26">
    <title>I left my heart on Europa</title>
    <artist>Ship of Nomads</artist>
</song>
<song dateplayed="2011-07-24 19:27:42">
    <title>Oh Ganymede</title>
    <artist>Beefachanga</artist>
</song>
<song dateplayed="2011-07-24 19:23:50">
    <title>Kallichore</title>
    <artist>Jewitt K. Sheppard</artist>
</song>
```

then:

```
<?php
$mysongs = simplexml_load_file('songs.xml');
echo $mysongs->song[0]->artist;
?>
```

Output on your browser: **Ship of Nomads**

credits: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/how-to-parse-xml-with-php5

Answer (score 2):

no, CURL does not have anything with parsing XML, it does not know anything about the content returned. it serves as a proxy to get content. it's up to you what to do with it.

use JSON if possible (and json_decode) - it's easier to work with, if not possible,  use any XML library for parsin such as DOMXML:
http://php.net/domxml

Comment: I agree to that . But why are tags not shown. I do an echo . Is it because of browser?

Comment: yes, browser treats XML as (X)HTML, so if > or < is encountered, it is treated as normal tag...

Comment: If you echo htmlentities(...) you'll see the full XML

Answer (score 2):

```
$sXML = download_page('http://alanstorm.com/atom');
// Comment This    
// $oXML = new SimpleXMLElement($sXML);
// foreach($oXML->entry as $oEntry){
//  echo $oEntry->title . "\n";
// }
// Use json encode
$xml = simplexml_load_string($sXML);
$json = json_encode($xml);
$arr = json_decode($json,true);
print_r($arr);
```

Comment: download_page(), really? At least when you suggest a function, stick to built-ins or define those you are proposing. Newbies can easily get lost. I suggest you edit this and replace it with a simple file_get_contents() the least.

Answer (score 1):

simple load xml file ..

```
$xml = @simplexml_load_string($retValuet);

$status = (string)$xml->Status; 
$operator_trans_id = (string)$xml->OPID;
$trns_id = (string)$xml->TID;
```

?>