# PHP - Parse XML with simplexml_load_string - Getting empty values with CDATA?

Tags: php, simplexml, cdata

When parsing an XML array like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Products>
  <Product>
    <Code>ABC-1001</Code>
    <Brand>ZCOM</Brand>
  </Product>
</Products>
```

I get an output of:

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
  (
    [Code] => AP1024-DDRII640
    [Brand] => ZCOM
  )
}
```

But when the XML is like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Products Code="ABC-1001">
  <Product>
    <Code><![CDATA[ABC-1001]]></Code>
    <Brand><![CDATA[ZCOM]]></Brand>
  </Product>
</Products>
```

It returns:

```
array
  0 => 
    array (size=12)
      '@attributes' => 
        array (size=1)
          'Code' => string 'ABC-1001' (length=8)
      'Code' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'Brand' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
```

This is how the XML is parsed from a URL:

```
$updateUrl = file_get_contents('http://www.someplace/xmlfeed/xml.cfm?asd=12345&uhg=9999');
$updateXml=<<<XML
$updateUrl
XML;
$updateXmlObject=json_decode(json_encode((array) simplexml_load_string($updateXml)), 1);
$updatePHPArray=$updateXmlObject['Product'];
```

And:

```
var_dump($updatePHPArray);exit;
```

Gives the output as above.

Now, why am I getting empty values in the second instance and how could I remedy this without access to the XML source?

Comment: what exactly is the point of getting a string, stuffing that string into ANOTHER string using a heredoc, then stuffing that second string into xml, forcing it to an array. json_encoding, json_decoding? That is just total cargo-cult programming.

Comment: @MarcB I am a noob... This was the best that I could come up with. Open to any better solutions hey :)

Comment: @MarcB I think that i encoded and decoded it to normalize the data if that makes sense? I recall having some characters or something that were giving me a hard time.

Comment: SimpleXML with cdata -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970602/php-how-to-handle-cdata-with-simplexmlelement

Comment: @BrainFooLong Thanks, did not spot this one.

Comment: @MarcB I'd still love to see how you would tackle this task, just saying :)

Comment: well, since there's some normalizing going on, then that's ok. but just for raw conversion: `$xml = simplexml_load_file('http:/...');` would do.

Comment: By using that `json_decode(json_encode())` hack, you've simultaneously thrown away *all the features of SimpleXML*, and introduced a whole load of unnecessary problems for yourself. The result of `simplexml_load_string`/`simplexml_load_file` is an object with lots of useful magic powers, don't just throw it away at your first opportunity.

Comment: @IndigoIdentity: Why do you convert the product to an array in the first place?

Comment: @hakre To process the data in various ways.

Comment: @IndigoIdentity: I have good news for you then: You don't neeed to convert to array. So this solves your problem already. Just access the data from the **SimpleXMLelement** object and you're already done. The problem you describe you have also immediately disappears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that the cast you're doing to array can return results different than the actual structure of the XML object.

Something like the following code should give you an array with the correct info:

```
$array = array_map('strval', (array) $xml->Product);
```

Take care you cast those parts to string of which you'll get the data from (in the example done via `strval()`). In the opposite, `json_encode()` is not working well with **SimpleXMLElement**.

Comment: Thanks, reading this and after the comment by @BrainFooLong , simply passing LIBXML_NOCDATA as the third argument within simplexml_load_string() will solve this. I saw this in the docs while reading the comments as u had suggested :)

Comment: @IndigoIdentity I can't stress enough that *LIBXML_NOCDATA is not necessary*. Just don't use hacks like `json_decode(json_encode($blah))`, and don't trust `var_dump`. Instead, read [the examples of how to use SimpleXML properly](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php).