# Parsing CDATA in XML with PHP with multiple elements in single tag

Tags: php, xml, cdata

I am using simple_xml_loader to parse xml document.

I then use xpath to specify the root tag from which I want to print its children nodes.

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file('url') or die("Error: Cannot create object");

$result = $xml->xpath('//category');
foreach ($result as $node){
    print $result;
}
```

Now I have problems printing the content of an element (i.e. ![CDATA[Refrigerators]). It is not get printed.

How do I fix it?

Comment: '<category id="1" parentId = "29"><![CDATA[Foo]]></category>'                        I want to print Foo.

Comment: As far as i understand, you can take it only by text proccesing. It is a XML comment. Parsers skip it

Comment: can you elaborate on text processing?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970602/php-how-to-handle-cdata-with-simplexmlelement