# Get attribute values SimpleXML Xpath PHP

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

```
<RESULTS>
    <ROW>
        <COLUMN NAME="ID"><![CDATA[001]]></COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="NAME"><![CDATA[ORG001]]></COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="CODE"><![CDATA[1234]]></COLUMN>
    </ROW>
</RESULTS>
```

Using simplexml / xpath i would like to return the attribute text for 'NAME' and 'CODE' for ID 001, there is many rows so the result would be different based on id number

**Edit:** 
accessing the CDATA isn't the problem here, it is returning the values of name and code where id = 001 etc

heres what i tried to get the name

`echo (string)$xml->xpath('/RESULT/ROW/COLUMN[@ID] = ["001"]/COLUMN[@Name="NAME"]');`

Thanks

Comment: What did you try? Can you show us your code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: How to handle <!\[CDATA\[ with SimpleXMLElement?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970602/php-how-to-handle-cdata-with-simplexmlelement)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you really try to do. As far as I understand...

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($x); // assuming XML in $x
$hit = (string)$xml->xpath("/RESULTS/ROW[COLUMN/@NAME='ID' and COLUMN/text() = '001']/COLUMN[@NAME='NAME']")[0];
```

Above code step by step:

- `(string)` will force the result to string, instead of object
- xpath-expression: get `<ROW>` with a child `<COLUMN>` with an attribute `NAME='ID'` and a value of `001`
- starting from that specific `<ROW>`, select a child `<COLUMN>` with an attribute of `NAME='NAME'`
- `xpath()` returns an array of `SimpleXml` elements, by `[0]` we select its first entry.
- be aware that this code lacks checking if there's a match at all.

see it working: https://eval.in/503464

**EDIT**:
Re-read the question. To get the result you want, select the `<ROW>` and then iterate over the `<COLUMN>`:

```
$hit = $xml->xpath("/RESULTS/ROW[COLUMN/@NAME='ID' and COLUMN/text() = '001']")[0];
foreach ($hit as $column)
    echo $column['NAME'] . ": " . $column . PHP_EOL;
```

Output:

```
ID: 001
NAME: ORG001
CODE: 1234
```

see https://eval.in/503493

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer, and humorus variable naming! is there an easy way to turn each column into a variable? Thanks :)