# Modify CDATA String and insert again in CDATA format?

Tags: php, xml, dom, simplexml

Actual I have one problem. I want to append something to string in CDATA format in a XML file.

```
<url><![CDATA[http://www.kinguin.net/category/1356/l-a-noire-steam-key/?nosalesbooster=1&country_store=1&currency=EUR]]</url>
```

After I modify the string with this code:

```
$doc = simplexml_import_dom($dom);
    $items = $doc->xpath('//url');
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        $node = dom_import_simplexml($item);
        $node->textContent .= 'appendIT';
    }
```

I get:

```
<url>http://www.kinguin.net/category/1356/l-a-noire-steam-key/?nosalesbooster=1&amp;country_store=1&amp;currency=EURappendIT]]</url>
```

But how can I say "Put it back into the CDATA format"?

And in addition. I want to send this url to my database. But without the `&amp;` char. So how can I get the url without the `&amp;`?

Greetings and Thank You!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Modify !\[CDATA\[\]\] in PHP? (XML)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42354598/modify-cdata-in-php-xml)

Answer (score 0):

As `CDATA` in XML stands for "character data", you can treat it as a string without parsing it. CDATA ends with `]]` (assume not nested CDATA), so

```
$xmlstrIn = '<url><![CDATA[http://www.kinguin.net/category/1356/l-a-noire-steam-key/?nosalesbooster=1&country_store=1&currency=EUR]]</url>';
$xmlstrOut = preg_replace('|(\]\])|', 'appendIT$1', $xmlstrIn);
```

and send `$xmlstrOut` to your database.

Hope this solves the problem (unless you are doing research of SimpleXML extension or something).

Regards,

Nick

Comment: And what's about the &amp;

Comment: &amp; won't be affected at all. 'preg_replace' finds closing ']]' and inserts 'appendIT'.

Comment: Can you provide a link to an example of a _nested CDATA_ structure? I am really interested in that.

Comment: here: `<link><![CDATA[http://www.kinguin.net/category/192/payday-the-heist-eu-steam-key/?nosalesbooster=1&country_store=1&currency=EUR]]></link>`