# Return XML from PHP SOAP Web Service

Tags: php, web-services, soap

I have a web service method which creates an XML string to be returned. When this method is called from SoapUI, it returns the entire XML as CDATA. I want the return value as XML and not as CDATA. I tried the jsonencode jsondecode approach that converts my xml to an array but in that case my SOAP return value contains 'Array'. Current response is: [CDATA[well formatted xml]] ...  I want the response to be: well formatted xml ...

Comment: Not sure I know what you are asking. Does this help? [PHP: How to handle <![CDATA[ with SimpleXMLElement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970602/php-how-to-handle-cdata-with-simplexmlelement) Maybe show us by sharing code and providing an example?

Comment: Current response is:
<soap....
...
<MessageNameResponse xsd:string>[CDATA[well formatted xml]]</...>
...
</soap>
I want the response to be:
<soap....
...
<MessageNameResponse xsd:string>well formatted xml</...>
...
</soap>

Comment: You'll have better luck getting an answer if you can update the question with that and format it nicely. Better the question, better the answers often. Provide everything we need to be able to answer.