# parse xml file with php and simplexml_load_file forget newline

Tags: php, xml, parsing

using php to parse this xml code:

```
<description><![CDATA[foobar

foobar2

foobar3]]></description>
```

The problem is when I parse with `simplexml_load_file` I forget the orginal format:

```
$content = simplexml_load_file("my_file.xml");
$a = $content->description;
echo $a;
```

```
foobar foobar2 foobar3
```

How can I preserve the original format?

**Note**: I can't edit the xml file, I must use `simplexml_load_file`

Comment: Are you displaying the result in a browser?

Comment: No I am saving the entri in a database

Comment: nl2br() works for me

Answer (score 1):

Your code is (mostly) correct. You might want to [force string conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970602/php-how-to-handle-cdata-with-simplexmlelement), as CDATA is tricky to manage:

```
$a = "{$content->description}"; // Notice the quotes and braces
echo $a;
```

Note that, as @NigelRen observed, your output **will not appear formatted** in a browser. To have it formatted you need to tell the browser HTML parser to do it:

```
echo "<pre>{$a}</pre>";
```

or use `nl2br()`.