# php parser xml with curl

Tags: php, xml, parsing, curl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP Curl , extract a XML response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561816/php-curl-extract-a-xml-response)

How to php parser xml with curl? Here is my code, how to get xml each item values? Thanks.

```
<?php
define("EMAIL_ADDRESS", "youlichika@hotmail.com");
$ch = curl_init();
$cv = curl_version();
$user_agent = "curl ${cv['version']} (${cv['host']}) libcurl/${cv['version']} ${cv['ssl_version']} zlib/${cv['libz_version']} <" . EMAIL_ADDRESS . ">"; 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $user_agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookies.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookies.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "deflate, gzip, identity");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=tokyo&format=xml&limit=2");
$xml = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
var_dump($xml);
?>
```

XML TREE

```
<SearchSuggestion version="2.0">
<Query xml:space="preserve">tokyo</Query>
<Section>
<Item>
<Text xml:space="preserve">Tokyo</Text>
<Description xml:space="preserve">
, officially , is one of the 47 prefectures of Japan.
</Description>
<Url xml:space="preserve">http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokyo</Url>
<Image source="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a6/Japan_Tokyo3.png/36px-Japan_Tokyo3.png" width="36" height="49"/>
</Item>
<Item>
<Text xml:space="preserve">Tokyo Broadcasting System</Text>
<Description xml:space="preserve">
(), TBS Holdings, Inc. or TBSHD, is a stockholding company in Tokyo, Japan. It is a parent company of a television network named and radio network named .
</Description>
<Url xml:space="preserve">
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokyo_Broadcasting_System
</Url>
</Item>
</Section>
</SearchSuggestion>
```

Comment: What a good thing that [no one has ever asked this before!](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+parse+xml)

Answer (score 11):

CURL has nothing to do with XML, it's simply a delivery mechanism that retrieves XML for you. It's like saying milk tastes different because one delivery driver uses a car and one uses a truck.

To process XML in PHP, use [DOM](http://php.net/dom) or [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php)

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($xml); // where $xml is the result from curl
... do whatever you want with the DOM object here ...
```

Comment: Fatal error: Class 'DOM' not found

Comment: If that's the case, then it was compiled as a separate module and needs to be installed and/or activated. What platform/OS are you on?

Comment: you want `$dom = new DOMDocument();`

Comment: @onteria: d'oh... thanks. I need a nap or something... Fixing up the answer...

Answer (score 5):

You can just load the result into `SimpleXML` and loop over the data. Here's an example:

```
define("EMAIL_ADDRESS", "youlichika@hotmail.com");
$ch = curl_init();
$cv = curl_version();
$user_agent = "curl ${cv['version']} (${cv['host']}) libcurl/${cv['version']} ${cv['ssl_version']} zlib/${cv['libz_version']} <" . EMAIL_ADDRESS . ">"; 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $user_agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookies.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookies.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "deflate, gzip, identity");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=tokyo&format=xml&limit=2");
$xml_data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

// Make sure we actually have something to parse
if($xml_data) {
  $parser = simplexml_load_string($xml_data);

  foreach($parser->Section as $section) {
    foreach($section->Item as $item) {
      echo "{$item->Text}\n\n{$item->Description}\n--------------------\n";
    }
  }
}
```

Here's some sample output:

```
$ php test.php
Tokyo


, officially , is one of the 47 prefectures of Japan.

--------------------
Tokyo Broadcasting System


(), TBS Holdings, Inc. or TBSHD, is a stockholding company in Tokyo, Japan. It is a parent company of a television network named and radio network named .

--------------------
```

Comment: simplexml seems more easy, no need install again.