# jQuery $.ajax() to PHP CURL

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, curl

I am looking to translate the following into PHP CURL.

```
$.ajax({
  url:"MY_URL",
  cache: false,
  type: "POST",
  data: "",
  dataType: "xml",
  success: function(data) { 
    alert('Eureka!')
    }
});
```

I'm particularly interested in figuring out how I have to alter the following to get the dataType set to xml. The following code is not working:

```
$ch = curl_init('MY_URL');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); // get the header 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array (
      "Content-Type: xml; charset=utf-8",
      "Expect: 100-continue",
      "Accept: xml"
     ));
```

Thanks!

Comment: "Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8",

Comment: The dataType parameter is used by jQuery's ajax function to *parse* the result. What do you expect curl to do ?

Comment: See here for various MIME types: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type

Comment: possible duplicate of [php parser xml with curl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6180669/php-parser-xml-with-curl)

Comment: Thanks. This cleared my misunderstanding of the documentation on the API with which I'm working. I'm porting a set of jQuery functions to a PHP class, and could not figure out why the response kept returning an HTML table when $.ajax() was specifying "dataType:xml". I see now that jQuery was just parsing the HTML as XML. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2):

Using the phery, you can do it in a pretty straightforward way (in http://phery-php-ajax.net/), I've been improving and using my library for the past 2 years:

```php
// file would be curl.php
Phery::instance()->set(array(
  'curl' => function($data){
    $ch = curl_init($data['url']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); // get the header 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array (
      "Content-Type: xml; charset=utf-8",
      "Expect: 100-continue",
      "Accept: xml"
    ));
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return PheryResponse::factory()->json(array('xml' => $data)); 
  }
))->process();
```

Then create a function with the ajax call to make it reusable:

```js
/* config would be {'url':'http://'} */
function curl(url){
  return phery.remote('curl', {'url': url}, {'target': 'curl.php'}, false);
}

curl('http://somesite/data.xml').bind('phery:json', function(event, data){
  // data.xml now contains the XML data you need
}).phery('remote'); // call the remote curl function
```