# Using curl with PHP from CLI

Tags: php, xml, curl

I am trying to run a PHP script from CLI and curl seems to return an empty string.

It works if I run the script from a browser, but not when I run it from CLI.
Just trying to get it working locally on wamp to begin with.

I understand that there are two different `php.ini` files being used here. Perhaps I'm missing something there? I can confirm the curl extension is loaded with `extension_loaded('curl')`.

Code:

```
function download_page($path) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $path);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 0);
    $retValue = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $retValue;
}
```

(Above code found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561816/php-curl-extract-an-xml-response))

And load it with:

```
$xml = new DomDocument();
$page = download_page("http://localhost/MySite/MyFile.xml");//In reality this file will be hosted on some webserver
$xml->loadXML($page); // Error here - empty string
// .. process XML file
```

Comment: try using `echo curl_error($ch);` to see any curl errors

Comment: This revealed a http 502 error. Something to do with my company's firewall?