# PHP: read a php url as xml and parse it

Tags: php, xml

i got a url like this one `http://somedomain.com/frieventexport.php` and the content of this url is a plain XML structure if I check out the source-code of the site:

[image]

How can I parse this URL and use it in PHP?
This script gives me an error… "Error loading XML".

```
<?php

    $xml_url = "http://somedomain.com/frieventexport.php";

    if (($response_xml_data = file_get_contents($xml_url))===false){
        echo "Error fetching XML\n";
    } else {
       libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
       $data = simplexml_load_string($response_xml_data);
       if (!$data) {
           echo "Error loading XML\n";
           foreach(libxml_get_errors() as $error) {
               echo "\t", $error->message;
           }
       } else {
          print_r($data);
       }
    }

?>
```

Comment: is there any data coming in $response_xml_data variable?
sometimes URL are not allowed to be read in file_get_contents. please check your ini settings too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the best options in my opinion is to use CURL to get the raw XML data from the url:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://somedomain.com/frieventexport.php" );

$xml = curl_exec( $curl );
curl_close( $curl );
```

You can then use DOMDocument to parse the xml:

```
$document = new DOMDocument;
$document->loadXML( $xml );
```

I would also recommend using `<![CDATA[]>` tags in your XML. Please read the following:

- [What does `<![CDATA[]]>` in XML mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2784200/540812)
- [CDATA Sections in XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA#CDATA_sections_in_XML)

More information about DOMDocument and usage

- [PHP.net DOMDocument documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)
- [W3Schools DOMDocument example](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_xml_dom.asp)

Comment: Thank you, `var_dump($document);` is giving me this https://s3.amazonaws.com/f.cl.ly/items/3V3Y2P3L41401Q102J12/Screen%20Shot%202015-02-16%20at%2015.00.03.png … How can I work with that xml now. How do I loop through the elements and read specific tags?

Comment: I'd recommend you look at the DOMDocument documentation. I'll link to it in my answer.

Comment: The documentation that you provide via link is very extensive in content and in my opinion does not help him solve his confusion with the null var_dump

Comment: @KurtLeadley that may be, but the question is "How can I parse this URL and use it in PHP?". I gave them more then what was asked for. Also, the documentation was added after he asked for more information about the link, see the first comment above.

Answer (score 1):

`file_get_contents()` is usually disabled if this is shared hosting, if not you can set `allow_url_fopen` in php.ini (however beware of the security risks). You can check the setting of this using `php_info()` or `var_dump(ini_get('allow_url_fopen'))` to show if it's allowed or not.

If you cannot do the above, you can use CURL to fetch external content

Comment: How would I do this using CURL? Can you give me an example please, thank you.

Comment: Plenty example out there, here is one to get you started ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/561816/php-curl-extract-an-xml-response

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$url = 'xml-file.xml';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
print_r($xml);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
$livescore_data = new SimpleXMLElement($file);
```