# Print XML in PHP 7

Tags: php, xml

Hi I want print a string xml (title) in php

I have tried that:

```
<?php
$xml = "<tracks>
<radioname>Radio</radioname>
<track>
<uniqueid>400000</uniqueid>
<title>Mask Off</title>
<artists>Future</artists>
</track>
</tracks>";

$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml); 
echo $xml->tracks->track->title;

?>
```

Comment: What's happening when you try that?

Comment: She does not show anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try this:

```
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><tracks>
<radioname>Radio</radioname>
<track>
<uniqueid>400000</uniqueid>
<title>Mask Off</title>
<artists>Future</artists>
</track>
</tracks>';

$xmlcont = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

echo $xmlcont->track->title;
```

Output will be:

```
Mask Off
```

Comment: File is on another page?? can you elaborate? if this works ,please  mark this as accepted so others would know this works.

Comment: i don't get this file on another page thing?? what exactly are you trying to do?? if you could elaborate your requirement may be i could helpu

Comment: I would like to extract the xml file from here: http://api.radionomy.com/currentsong.cfm?radiouid=80b5e81c-c769-478a-aee7-fbe149aacfe3&apikey=cf415862-c0ac-4085-bc03-be80a26f9063&callmeback=yes&type=xml&cover=yes&previous=yes.xml
And then print title from that file

Comment: you might want to read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28538787/php-read-a-php-url-as-xml-and-parse-it

Comment: it can be done.. can you ask this new requirement  as a new question.. so i could properly answer there.