# Parsing curl results from a PubMed query and formatting them into a citation

Tags: php, xslt, curl, xpath, pubmed

This is a follow-up question to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40984052/parsing-curl-results-as-simplexml-and-using-those-to-create-new-xml-data) question.

Same idea: I'm pulling data from PubMed as XML and using curl to process those results. This allows me to grab the information I need (a list of pub IDs) and use that as a variable for ANOTHER PubMed scrape. The $name will eventually be dynamic.

```
<?php 
$name = 'white,theodore';
// Return xml data from PubMed based on author search name
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esearch.fcgi?db=pubmed&term='.$name.'[author]&retmode=xml&retmax=50');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, 1);

$output = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

// Parse the results and concatenate into a string of Publication IDs
$xml=simplexml_load_string($output);
$idList = $xml->IdList;
$ids = "";
foreach($idList->children() as $id) {
    $ids .= $id . ",";
}

// Plug that string of IDs into another PubMed search, this one returning XML data for Publication Summaries
$path = 'https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esummary.fcgi?db=pubmed&id='.$ids;

$ch2 = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_URL, $path);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, 1);

$data = curl_exec($ch2);

curl_close($ch2);
// Parse those results and print only what is needed for Citation format
$cxml=simplexml_load_string($data);
foreach($cxml->children() as $docsum) {
  foreach($docsum->children() as $item) {
    foreach($item->children() as $details) {
        if ((string) $details['Name'] === 'Author') {echo $details . "., ";}
    }
    if ((string) $item['Name'] === 'FullJournalName') { echo $item . ". "; }
    if ((string) $item['Name'] === 'Title') { echo "<strong>" . $item . "</strong> "; }
    if ((string) $item['Name'] === 'Volume') { echo "Vol." . $item . ", "; }
    if ((string) $item['Name'] === 'Issue') { echo "Issue" . $item . ". "; }
    if ((string) $item['Name'] === 'PubDate') { echo $item . ". "; }
    foreach($item->children() as $details) {
            if ((string) $details['Name'] === 'PubType') {echo $details . ", ";}
        }
  }
  echo "</br></br>";
}

?>
```

Which returns the following XML data (this is ONE result).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE eSummaryResult PUBLIC "-//NLM//DTD esummary v1 20041029//EN" "https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/eutils/dtd/20041029/esummary-v1.dtd">
<eSummaryResult>
  <DocSum>
    <Id>27431223</Id>
    <Item Name="PubDate" Type="Date">2016 Oct</Item>
    <Item Name="EPubDate" Type="Date">2016 Sep 23</Item>
    <Item Name="Source" Type="String">Antimicrob Agents Chemother</Item>
    <Item Name="AuthorList" Type="List">
      <Item Name="Author" Type="String">Bhattacharya S</Item>
      <Item Name="Author" Type="String">Sobel JD</Item>
      <Item Name="Author" Type="String">White TC</Item>
    </Item>
    <Item Name="LastAuthor" Type="String">White TC</Item>
    <Item Name="Title" Type="String">A Combination Fluorescence Assay Demonstrates Increased Efflux Pump Activity as a Resistance Mechanism in Azole-Resistant Vaginal Candida albicans Isolates.</Item>
    <Item Name="Volume" Type="String">60</Item>
    <Item Name="Issue" Type="String">10</Item>
    <Item Name="Pages" Type="String">5858-66</Item>
    <Item Name="LangList" Type="List">
    <Item Name="Lang" Type="String">English</Item>
    </Item>
    <Item Name="NlmUniqueID" Type="String">0315061</Item>
    <Item Name="ISSN" Type="String">0066-4804</Item>
    <Item Name="ESSN" Type="String">1098-6596</Item>
    <Item Name="PubTypeList" Type="List">
      <Item Name="PubType" Type="String">Journal Article</Item>
    </Item>
    <Item Name="RecordStatus" Type="String">Unknown status</Item>
    <Item Name="PubStatus" Type="String">epublish</Item>
    <Item Name="ArticleIds" Type="List">
      <Item Name="pubmed" Type="String">27431223</Item>
      <Item Name="pii" Type="String">AAC.01252-16</Item>
      <Item Name="doi" Type="String">10.1128/AAC.01252-16</Item>
      <Item Name="pmc" Type="String">PMC5038269</Item>
      <Item Name="rid" Type="String">27431223</Item>
      <Item Name="eid" Type="String">27431223</Item>
      <Item Name="pmcid" Type="String">pmc-id: PMC5038269;embargo-date: 2017/04/01;</Item>
    </Item>
    <Item Name="DOI" Type="String">10.1128/AAC.01252-16</Item>
    <Item Name="History" Type="List">
      <Item Name="received" Type="Date">2016/06/10 00:00</Item>
      <Item Name="accepted" Type="Date">2016/07/12 00:00</Item>
      <Item Name="pmc-release" Type="Date">2017/04/01 00:00</Item>
      <Item Name="entrez" Type="Date">2016/07/20 06:00</Item>
      <Item Name="pubmed" Type="Date">2016/07/20 06:00</Item>
      <Item Name="medline" Type="Date">2016/07/20 06:00</Item>
    </Item>
    <Item Name="References" Type="List"></Item>
    <Item Name="HasAbstract" Type="Integer">1</Item>
    <Item Name="PmcRefCount" Type="Integer">0</Item>
    <Item Name="FullJournalName" Type="String">Antimicrobial agents and chemotherapy</Item>
    <Item Name="ELocationID" Type="String">doi: 10.1128/AAC.01252-16</Item>
    <Item Name="SO" Type="String">2016 Oct;60(10):5858-66</Item>
</DocSum>

</eSummaryResult>
</br></br>
```

Which echoes thus:

> 2016 Oct. Bhattacharya S., Sobel JD., White TC., A Combination
>   Fluorescence Assay Demonstrates Increased Efflux Pump Activity as a
>   Resistance Mechanism in Azole-Resistant Vaginal Candida albicans
>   Isolates. Vol.60, Issue10. Journal Article, Antimicrobial agents and
>   chemotherapy.
>
> 2015. Zavrel M., White TC., Medically important fungi respond to azole drugs: an update. Vol.10, Issue8. Journal Article, Review, Future
>         microbiology.
> 2016. Esquivel BD., Smith AR., Zavrel M., White TC., Azole drug import into the pathogenic fungus Aspergillus fumigatus. Vol.59, Issue6.
>         Journal Article, Antimicrobial agents and chemotherapy.
>
> 2015 Apr. Achterman RR., Moyes DL., Thavaraj S., Smith AR., Blair KM.,
>   White TC., Naglik JR., Dermatophytes activate skin keratinocytes via
>   mitogen-activated protein kinase signaling and induce immune
>   responses. Vol.83, Issue4. Journal Article, Infection and immunity.
>
> 2015 Feb 3. Ford CB., Funt JM., Abbey D., Issi L., Guiducci C.,
>   Martinez DA., Delorey T., Li BY., White TC., Cuomo C., Rao RP., Berman
>   J., Thompson DA., Regev A., The evolution of drug resistance in
>   clinical isolates of Candida albicans. Vol.4, Issue. Journal Article,
>   eLife.
>
> 2014 Aug 1. White TC., Findley K., Dawson TL Jr., Scheynius A.,
>   Boekhout T., Cuomo CA., Xu J., Saunders CW., Fungi on the skin:
>   dermatophytes and Malassezia. Vol.4, Issue8. Journal Article, Review,
>   Cold Spring Harbor perspectives in medicine.
>
> 2014 Jan. Maguire SL., Wang C., Holland LM., Brunel F., Neuvéglise C.,
>   Nicaud JM., Zavrel M., White TC., Wolfe KH., Butler G., Zinc finger
>   transcription factors displaced SREBP proteins as the major Sterol
>   regulators during Saccharomycotina evolution. Vol.10, Issue1. Journal
>   Article, PLoS genetics.
>
> 2013 Nov 15. Campoli P., Perlin DS., Kristof AS., White TC., Filler
>   SG., Sheppard DC., Pharmacokinetics of posaconazole within epithelial
>   cells and fungi: insights into potential mechanisms of action during
>   treatment and prophylaxis. Vol.208, Issue10. Journal Article, The
>   Journal of infectious diseases.
>
> 2013 Jul 8. Achterman RR., White TC., Dermatophytes. Vol.23, Issue13.
>   Journal Article, Current biology : CB.
>
> ETC.

That all works great and produces citations with only the data I need BUT I cannot reorder the results so Author comes first, PubDate comes last, etc. I have tried a number of options, but I'm not familiar enough with any of them and can't seem to crack it.

I've tried attaching an XSLT style sheet but I think that's not working because I'm not actually outputting an XML file. Maybe?

I've tried using the following XPath instead of the SimpleXML block at the bottom to return the citations but keep getting blank results. Because all the data is tagged as `<Item>`, I'm trying unsuccessfully to use the Name attributes.

```
$content = simplexml_load_string($data);
$results = $content->xpath('Item[@Name]');
foreach($results as $result) {
  $title = $result->xpath('[@Name="Title"]');
  // Make sure there's an author attribute
  if($title) {
    // because we have a list of elements even if there's one result
    $items = $title[0]->attributes();
    $title = $items['value'];
  }
echo $results;
}
```

I've also tried DOMXPath and GetElementsByTagName to no avail.

Basically, I'm stuck. I've tried so many variations of each and gotten so many errors I feel like I'm flying in circles. Anyone with more Xpath or XSLT experience have an idea?

Comment: Sorry, yes. It actually echoes in citation format (not shown in question - I'll add it). The desired result is exactly that, to re-order those XML nodes within that citation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following pure XSLT solution (no `foreach` loop needed) which handles your node re-ordering and even final output as XSLT can transform XML content to text (i.e., PHP string) and of course even HTML.

Leave your entire CURL call just as is but replace the nested `foreach` looping. Below the XSLT script is embedded as string and requires PHP's `php_xsl` extension enabled in .ini file to access PHP's built-in XSLT 1.0 processor (i.e., libxslt):

```
// ... same CURL call ...

// Parse those results and print only what is needed for Citation format
$cxml=simplexml_load_string($data);

$xslstr = '<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output indent="yes" method="text"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="DocSum">
    <xsl:if test="Item[@Name=\'AuthorList\' and .!=\'\']">
        <xsl:for-each select="Item[@Name=\'AuthorList\' and .!=\'\']/*">
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
            <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>           
        </xsl:for-each><xsl:text>. </xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>

    <xsl:if test="Item[@Name=\'FullJournalName\' and .!=\'\']">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(\'&lt;strong&gt;\', Item[@Name=\'FullJournalName\'], 
                                     \'&lt;/strong&gt;\')" />
        <xsl:text>. </xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="Item[@Name=\'Title\' and .!=\'\']">                        
        <xsl:value-of select="Item[@Name=\'Title\']" /><xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="Item[@Name=\'Volume\' and .!=\'\']">
        <xsl:value-of select="Item[@Name=\'Volume\']" /><xsl:text>. </xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="Item[@Name=\'Issue\' and .!=\'\']">
        <xsl:value-of select="Item[@Name=\'Issue\']" /><xsl:text>. </xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="Item[@Name=\'PubDate\' and .!=\'\']">
        <xsl:value-of select="Item[@Name=\'PubDate\']" /><xsl:text>. </xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>

    <xsl:if test="Item[@Name=\'PubTypeList\' and .!=\'\']">
        <xsl:for-each select="Item[@Name=\'PubTypeList\']/*">
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
            <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>           
        </xsl:for-each><xsl:text>. </xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>

    <xsl:text>&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>     
</xsl:stylesheet>';

$xsl=simplexml_load_string($xslstr);

// XSLT TRANSFORMATION
$proc = new XSLTProcessor;
$proc->importStyleSheet($xsl); 
$newXML = $proc->transformToXML($cxml);

echo $newXML;
```

**Output**

[image: Citations Output]

Comment: Wow! Thanks for this. I'm currently getting a `Fatal error: Class 'XSLTProcessor' not found` error which I'm assuming means php_xsl is NOT enabled on the server. I've got a call into our IS guys. Hopefully they can get that switched on/installed.

Comment: Sorry, can't edit. But in the meantime, can you explain just a couple things in the code so I can learn? I'd really appreciate it. 
I never thought to include the XSLT inline. Nice. On the attributes you use a backslash in front of the single quotes. Is that so it recognizes them as starting/finishing a string? Also, why the empty `<xsl:text>` after each value-of line?

Comment: Single quotes are embedded to escape the single quotes being used to wrap PHP string. They would not be needed if you parse XSLT from file. And the empty `<xsl:text>` is to add a space between the values or they will be flushed together. In fact, I just noticed you used punctuation -periods and commas which I have updated script with as well.

Comment: Turned on php_xsl and everything works great. Now I just have to figure out how to exclude the additional punctuation if the field is empty. I tried to repurpose your 'if:test=' statement but because I'm looking for a value of the selects (in particular, Issue and Pages), I think I'm getting all the single/double quotes jacked up.

Comment: See update, wrapping each node in `<xsl:if>` tags to avoid empty punctuation.

Comment: I tried that before but it doesn't seem to be doing anything. Based on some searches I did, I need to check for and Empty Value, not the existence of the node maybe? That was where I tried doing `<xsl:if test="value-of select...` but couldn't make that work either.