# Get and evaluate curl response in Jenkins

Tags: php, json, bash, curl, jenkins

I am trying to get the response of a Http post with curl in Jenkins, I have the following script:

`curl -X POST -k -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data-binary "@/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Folder/sessions.json"` http://mypage/Data/file.php

As you can see I am sending to **file.php** a **json file**, and then I am calling some functions and am returning a specific result.

With that script, I am getting the result I want, but I want to evaluate that result, let's say for example the result was "OK", then I want to assign the result to a variable, and then say **if $result=="OK" then** do this **else** do that. How can I do that, I have tried something like this:

```
if $response == "true" then exit 1 fi
```

But it does not seem to work out, does anyone know how it can be done?

They marked it as similar to this question
[PHP cURL, extract an XML response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561816/php-curl-extract-an-xml-response)
, but I don't see how, because I am not talking about php code, bash code, and I want to store the curl result in a variable....

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the status code if you only need to check if the request was successful :

```
status=$(curl --write-out '%{http_code}' \
    -s -o /dev/null \
    -H "Accept: application/json" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    --data-binary "@/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Folder/sessions.json" \
    "http://mypage/Data/file.php")

if [ "$status" == "200" ]; then
    echo "request was successful"
else
    echo "error status : $status"
fi
```

with :

- `--write-out '%{http_code}'` : output the status code
- `-o /dev/null` : doesn't to output the body
- `-s` : doesn't display connection log

As you have specified `Accept: application/json`, you expect a response in JSON format, so you could use [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) JSON parser to parse it :

If the response is :

```
{ "status": true }
```

then you can do the following :

```
status=$(curl -s -H "Accept: application/json" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    --data-binary "@/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Folder/sessions.json" \
    "http://mypage/Data/file.php" | jq -r '.status')

if [ "$status" == "true" ]; then
    echo "request was successful"
else
    echo "error status : $status"
fi
```

If the response is not in JSON format and the response is `OK` :

```
status=$(curl -s -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    --data-binary "@/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Folder/sessions.json" \
    "http://mypage/Data/file.php")

if [ "$status" == "OK" ]; then
    echo "request was successful"
else
    echo "error status : $status"
fi
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!!