# XML string is empty after parsing to SimpleXML in php

Tags: php, xml

Using PHP I make a call to an API. I use curl for this and the response should be XML. But the response of my call is a string which contains the XML content. So I wanted to parse it using simplexml_load_string. 
But then, I get an empty object:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#839 (0) { }
```

This is my call:

```
$curl = curl_init($this->api_base . $this->endpoint);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC );
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $this->get_auth_string());
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip,deflate');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
    'Content-Type: application/xml',
    'Accept: application/xml',
    'Connection: Keep-Alive'
]);
$response = curl_exec($curl);
$curl_error = curl_error($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

What is wrong with that? How can I get a real XML to loop through?

Comment: check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561816/php-curl-extract-an-xml-response

Comment: That looks like the output you'd get if you ran `simplexml_load_string` over a single empty XML element (e.g. **<foo />**) - if your Curl call wasn't returning XML at all, you'd get false instead of an object. Is the value in `$response` definitely what you're expecting? Importantly, using in-built debugging tools like `var_dump` is a bad idea, as they don't give you a full representation of the object. You could also be seeing this if your document was namespaced, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44894426/reference-how-do-i-handle-namespaces-tags-and-attributes-with-colon-in-in-si

Comment: @iainn yes, the response (string) is exactly what I expect and a correct complete XML document

Comment: @lovelace: This code is similar to mine I think... but mine doesnt work

Comment: @FZC3 It sounds like it's namespaced then. `var_dump` won't display namespaced child elements and attributes of an XML document, but it doesn't mean they aren't there (see https://eval.in/1028340). You need to use SimpleXML's internal functionality to parse it - the link to the other question I posted above has a lot more details.

Comment: @iainn response:  
`<search:search-result xmlns:seller="http://services.mobile.de/schema/seller" xmlns:ad="http://services.mobile.de/schema/ad" xmlns:search="http://services.mobile.de/schema/search" xmlns:financing="http://services.mobile.de/schema/common/financing-1.0" xmlns:resource="http://services.mobile.de/schema/resource" xmlns:error="http://services.mobile.de/schema/common/error-1.0"><search:total>2</search:total><search:page-size>20</search:page-size><search:max-pages>1</search:max-pages><search:ads>...</search:ads></search:search-result>`  ----- I need to loop **<search:ads>**

Comment: @iainn I tried using the namespaces like in your example, but the loop does not output anything...