# How to access specific node in XML using PHP

Tags: php, html, xml, file-get-contents

I am trying to print a specific node from a user uploaded XML file. I have looked into using the [SimpleXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578832/how-to-convert-xml-into-array-in-php) extension and [cURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561816/php-curl-extract-an-xml-response) to do this to no avail. Here is my current code that POSTS the XML and then prints it into a string with `file_get_contents`.

```html
<?php
$file = $_FILES['uploadedFile'];
if (is_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name']) && $file['error'] == 0) { 
    echo "The file name was: " . $file['name'] . "<br><br>";
    echo "The file type is: " . $file['type'] . "<br><br>";
    $xml = htmlentities(file_get_contents($file['tmp_name']));

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($xml);
    echo "</pre>";

    echo "Contact Email: ".$xml["data"]["contactEmail"];
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>    
    <title>Test XML</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="uploadedFile" size="50" maxlength="25"><br>
        <input type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

This page will be receiving the same structured XML and returns this:

```html
The file name was: Order_100031.xml

The file type is: text/xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <data>
      <contactEmail>fake@email.com</contactEmail>
      <contactTelephone>1234567890</contactTelephone>
      <btNameCompany>John Doe</btNameCompany>
      <btStreet>123 Testington Blvd</btStreet>
      <btAddress2>Apt. 404</btAddress2>
      <btCity>Fairchild</btCity>
      <btState>WI</btState>
      <btZip>54720</btZip>
      <btCountry>US</btCountry>
      <item>
        <quantity>1</quantity>
        <productId>201</productId>memo
      </item>
    </data>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>

Contact Email: &
```

I believe that my syntax is wrong when trying to `echo` the contactEmail node. Do I need to include the envelope and body when trying to access it?

Comment: Why are you using `htmlentities` on the XML when you read it in? Where are you actually parsing the XML into something usable? AFAICT you're just reading it into a string then attempting to use it as an array?